# Instakk and Run Ubuntu on Win' XP 32bit

Tags: windows-xp

I Have a Win' Xp 32bit OS.
I'd like to install on my current OS Ubuntu ,so I'll be able to execute Ubuntu from my Win' OS.
Could you please provide me the proper download link ?

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

This is actually quite easy,  I have done it myself before I build another HDD into my system.  Make shore u have an Ubuntu 32bit.iso version.  Just put it into u CD ROM and click install.  The System will ask u if u would like to create a partition.  NB Important is the ending - .iso  .  Have fun,  just u should always make shore that u important files are safe.  I do this by saving them on an external HDD.